# JPG with ICC profile looks faded in browser

Tags: photoshop, web, srgb

When i am done processing my image in Photoshop i will want to save it as a .JPG file.

When the save dialog opens it has a checkmark next to "ICC profile: sRGB IEC61966-2.1".

I understand that this embeds the sRGB colorspace header withing the image. So here is my question:

If i embed the sRGB profile then why does the image look faded in the browser? I understand that sRGB should be the default for browsers/web? Therefore my image with an embedded sRGB profile should display properly.

Comment: What browser? Not all browsers actually read the ICC profile embedded in the metadata.

Comment: Hmm, browsers should default to sRGB, and whether the sRGB profile is embedded or not should not matter?

If the browser uses the profile, it gets sRGB, if not, then it defaults to sRGB. 

What am i missing here - why do images with embedded sRGB profile look different in browsers?

Comment: What is the gamut of the monitor you are using, and do you have it color profiled?

Comment: @elelont Not all browsers default to sRGB. Just because they *should* doesn't mean they all *do*.

Comment: I don't think sRGB IEC61966-2.1 is the only "flavor" of sRGB, either. There should be no noticeable difference between any of them, however.

Comment: @MichaelClark Yeah, exactly. I think, in fact, most default to sending unmodified values right along.

Comment: Is this happening on your computer only or everywhere? Do you have wide gamut monitor? How exactly you get your monitor profile that you use on the computer where you edit and asses the images? How do you convert to sRGB, convert or assign? Can you post an example? What color space you use before you convert to sRGB? Finally, do you see this behavior only with your images, or with all images? Edit: what browsers we are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess. You note in a comment that "If the browser uses the profile, it gets sRGB, if not, then it defaults to sRGB." But, that's not necessarily the case. The browser may say "If there's a profile, I'll treat the photo as color managed" and "If there's no profile, show it in the monitor's native colors". That native space *may* be sRGB, and for a long time, that was a fine approximation of reality, but isn't necessarily true especially if you have a fancy new monitor.

There's a page here: http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html which goes into detail. The top demo lets you mouse over to see the difference between Adobe RGB and sRGB in taggged and untagged versions; scroll down to see different color spaces compared to the same color space untagged. On my laptop (with a terrible yet color-profiled screen) and Firefox, Adobe RGB shows a more visible jump, but untagged sRGB is definitely also different from tagged. (While tagged Adobe RGB and sRGB both appear indistinguishable.)

I also notice that on my system, the untagged sRGB image shows up slightly darker and with more contrast. That sounds like it might be what you describe when you say the one with the embedded profile is "faded". So, I think bottom line is that the version with the ICC profile is probably actually correct; if you want it to be "punchier", adjust your processing accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply.

The untagged sRGB image shows up slightly darker and with more contrast for me as well.

But what does it mean if the browser says: 
"If there's a profile, I'll treat the photo as color managed". 

Does it have like a second layer of color profile on top of the embedded sRGB profile? I don't quite understand how the image produced by the browser on top of the same sRGB space is different than the one i see in IrfanView, Photoshop etc? Why doesn't the browser render the image like the rest of the programs (IrfanView, Photoshop)?

Comment: I _expect_ that those other programs are actually treating images without a profile as sRGB, and _those_ might look different in the browser (which treats them as monitor-native, and we hope it's close enough to sRGB). If you're saying that the _tagged_ image looks different in the browser and the other viewers, there's a different problem, and something is messed up with (probably the browers') interpretation of the profile.

Comment: Okay, i investigated this a bit more, i open the raw file in PS (photoshop):

1) Save the file as jpg WITHOUT ICC profile
BROWSER != PS |
IRFANVIEW == BROWSER |    

2) Save the file as jpg WITH ICC profile
BROWSER == PS | 
PS != IRFANVIEW |    

Therefore i assume that IrfanView (and Paint and Photos etc) do not read the ICC profile - is that correct?
Strange thing is that PS displays JPG with ICC and without EXACTLY the same. How is that possible?
http://www.upload.ee/image/5461652/Different.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I think what's going on is that A) PS and Browser are color-management aware, B) PS defaults to sRGB for untagged, C) Browser defaults to non-color-managed for untagged, and D) Irfanview (and etc) are just plain not aware. Can you confirm that the ICC and not versions both look the same in Irfanview?

Comment: Yes i can confirm that ICC does not matter in IrfanView.

Also, ICC does not matter in PS. I discovered that my windows color profile was set to ProPhoto - it seems that PS uses that value, since embedded ICC profile has no effect. 

Strange thing is that PS is the only program that is affected by windows profile.

Comment: @ele-lont: when working with untagged images the "working space" settings takes effect.  " I discovered that my windows color profile was set to ProPhoto" - i.e. monitor profile?

Comment: PS with and without profile looks the same: PS has a setting where you specify what happens if you open an image without profile. One option is alert, another silent assigning of a profile like sRGB. Look at your setting, it should give you the explanation you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

By experiment, I've found that some applications ignore an ICC profile that is sRGB (even though the application has deliberately added it).  Others (e.g., PTGui) deleted the flag that indicates that sRGB has already been applied.

The whole area is a mess ...